# How can i get information with javascript about the device which the user used to get on my asp.net webapp?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, tracking

I am working on a WebApp with C# asp.net and i want to get some information about the device of the user which is on my webapp. For example the browser, browser version, operating system and os version. I want to get the information with javascript like it is showed on this page (https://clientjs.org/) but i don't know how to use this with asp.net.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will help (from https://medium.com/creative-technology-concepts-code/detect-device-browser-and-version-using-javascript-8b511906745 ):

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';
    
    var module = {
        options: [],
        header: [navigator.platform, navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, navigator.vendor, window.opera],
        dataos: [
            { name: 'Windows Phone', value: 'Windows Phone', version: 'OS' },
            { name: 'Windows', value: 'Win', version: 'NT' },
            { name: 'iPhone', value: 'iPhone', version: 'OS' },
            { name: 'iPad', value: 'iPad', version: 'OS' },
            { name: 'Kindle', value: 'Silk', version: 'Silk' },
            { name: 'Android', value: 'Android', version: 'Android' },
            { name: 'PlayBook', value: 'PlayBook', version: 'OS' },
            { name: 'BlackBerry', value: 'BlackBerry', version: '/' },
            { name: 'Macintosh', value: 'Mac', version: 'OS X' },
            { name: 'Linux', value: 'Linux', version: 'rv' },
            { name: 'Palm', value: 'Palm', version: 'PalmOS' }
        ],
        databrowser: [
            { name: 'Chrome', value: 'Chrome', version: 'Chrome' },
            { name: 'Firefox', value: 'Firefox', version: 'Firefox' },
            { name: 'Safari', value: 'Safari', version: 'Version' },
            { name: 'Internet Explorer', value: 'MSIE', version: 'MSIE' },
            { name: 'Opera', value: 'Opera', version: 'Opera' },
            { name: 'BlackBerry', value: 'CLDC', version: 'CLDC' },
            { name: 'Mozilla', value: 'Mozilla', version: 'Mozilla' }
        ],
        init: function () {
            var agent = this.header.join(' '),
                os = this.matchItem(agent, this.dataos),
                browser = this.matchItem(agent, this.databrowser);
            
            return { os: os, browser: browser };
        },
        matchItem: function (string, data) {
            var i = 0,
                j = 0,
                html = '',
                regex,
                regexv,
                match,
                matches,
                version;
            
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
                regex = new RegExp(data[i].value, 'i');
                match = regex.test(string);
                if (match) {
                    regexv = new RegExp(data[i].version + '[- /:;]([\\d._]+)', 'i');
                    matches = string.match(regexv);
                    version = '';
                    if (matches) { if (matches[1]) { matches = matches[1]; } }
                    if (matches) {
                        matches = matches.split(/[._]+/);
                        for (j = 0; j < matches.length; j += 1) {
                            if (j === 0) {
                                version += matches[j] + '.';
                            } else {
                                version += matches[j];
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        version = '0';
                    }
                    return {
                        name: data[i].name,
                        version: parseFloat(version)
                    };
                }
            }
            return { name: 'unknown', version: 0 };
        }
    };
    
    var e = module.init(),
        debug = '';
    
    debug += 'os.name = ' + e.os.name + '<br/>';
    debug += 'os.version = ' + e.os.version + '<br/>';
    debug += 'browser.name = ' + e.browser.name + '<br/>';
    debug += 'browser.version = ' + e.browser.version + '<br/>';
    
    debug += '<br/>';
    debug += 'navigator.userAgent = ' + navigator.userAgent + '<br/>';
    debug += 'navigator.appVersion = ' + navigator.appVersion + '<br/>';
    debug += 'navigator.platform = ' + navigator.platform + '<br/>';
    debug += 'navigator.vendor = ' + navigator.vendor + '<br/>';
    
    document.getElementById('log').innerHTML = debug;
}());
```

```html
<div id="log"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get info about device in window. navigator and window.location objects.

If you want to get control over device capabilities [see this](https://webrtc.org)